# How to separate li's equally

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I have a `UL > li's` in my html, and the li's are set to `float: left`.

My doubt is how to separate them, inside a father div, equally, so that doesn't matter how many li's are in the ul, they still have the same spacing between them?

If li's are not 'good' to do that, what is better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per I understand is better you can write like this:

```css
li + li{
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

You can also use `display:table` property for this. Write like this:

```css
ul{
    display:table;
    width:100%
}
li{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: it's means there no margin-left in first LI.

Comment: It means that it will select any LI with an immediately preceeding (one before) LI. So it will not select the first, but all the others

Answer (score 0):

You may set a border to the `ul` and set a margin to child `li`s. Or you may set border both to `ul` and `li`s. The reason for parent border is, when `li`s merge, they will combine their borders creating a **double** border where they meet.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/57Jna/)*** is a Live Demo showing both methods.